# Business logic in the models?

Tags: mvc, asp.net-mvc, business-logic, model

I use the repository pattern for data handling.

In my DAL folder i have IUserRepository, UserRepository and UserContext. Inside the models folder i have a class called User like *id*, *username*  etc.

I read on the internet that I should do as less as possible in the controller. What do they mean?

I want to determine where to put the business logic For example I want to page a login page. What would happen if I put the login function alongside the models?

```
using IndividueleOpdracht.Dal;

namespace IndividueleOpdracht.Models
{
    public class AccountModel
    {
        public void Login(string username, string password)
        {
            // Do something with the repositories?
        }
    }
}
```

And then just call the AccountModel.Login method in the controller?

Comment: You need to spend more time with [Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) first, before you ask questions like this here.

Comment: I made this question more objective by asking "what" instead of "why," and wonder if it can be re-opened in its current form.

Answer (score 3):

> I read on the internet that I should do as less as possible in the
>   controller. What do they mean?

They mean the Controller is a part of the UI. And you should do only UI-related things inside it. If you need to so something with your model data, you place those actions into another layer (bussiness layer, logic layer, call it whatever you like) and call that layer from the controller.

> I want to determine where to put the business logic For example I want
>   to page a login page. What would happen if I put the login function
>   alongside the models?

You need to follow [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) when determining where to put things. Login does not look to me like a method of the user model itself. More like it belongs to authorization / authentication module of your business layer. But you decide of course.